# Create a Zoom in/out feature for reputation graph?

Tags: feature-request

The Reputation Graph in Activity Tab looks good as it shows our reputation over time.
But, We can't zoom in/out that graph.

[image]

There are some views of reputation such as `post`,`time` and `graph`.
Here, the graph view is also good looking in `Bar format`.

[image]

---

I suggest to create a new view(in `Line Format`) in the reputation tab that is same as in Activity tab but it should be zoomed out.

It will really look good because we can track our reputation which is in same view(Line Format) but as zoomed-out.

---

My suggestions for this features are as below:

1. Create a zoom-out feature for existing graph in small reputation tab (figure 1.)

OR

2. Create a new view for Line View of Graph.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/users/9162680/rohit-gaikwad?tab=reputation

Comment: @AleksandrM: Better yet, http://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation

Comment: @AleksandrM, thanks. It would also look good if it is provided in current reputation tab http://stackoverflow.com/users/6813506/rohit-gaikwad?tab=reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I asked question about the similar theme: [My Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342358/how-to-change-the-scale-of-a-reputation-plot)
It was closed but I still not get the answer (maybe because I'm not really good in understanding of the html and browser linking).
I read comments here and made some workaround and found some useful information about this. Hope it can be useful for another users

---

My answer is:

[stackexchange.com/users/%userID/?tab=reputation](https://stackexchange.com/users/6396905/mikhail-sam)

The interesting moment that you can't go just to see all the users.
But we can watch user's ID into the link on his page (usually this ID is just a set of numbers: 6396905 ).

[stackexchange.com/users/](https://stackexchange.com/users/) - Page Not Found error.

For watching your own page you can go

[stackexchange.com/users/current](https://stackexchange.com/users/current)

and
[stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=reputation](https://stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=reputation) to watch your own rep plot