# How to change the scale of a reputation plot

Tags: support, reputation, user-interface, reputation-graph

Just for my interest sometimes I like to watch some activity plot. [image]

Can I scale it anyway?

Comment: Sort of. Use [the full graph here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4960953/mikhail-sam?tab=reputation&sort=graph). Though that isn't a line graph, it's a column graph. Why do you want to change the scale? Do you just mean *zoom in*?

Comment: "select an area by dragging across the lower chart"  doesnt work for me. Maybe for him either.

Comment: What browser are you using, @theoretisch?

Comment: I usually use Opera (42.0.2393.137) but on Chrome it doesn't work either for me. (tried it just now) @CodyGray

Comment: Odd. Works just fine for me in Chrome (Mac and Windows), even a slightly-out-of-date version. @theoretisch

Comment: hmm, I don't know. If I try it just nothing happens. But thank you! @CodyGray

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Chrome either....but you can always grab the data from http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and make your own graph